# What is the minimum size of that a segment can take in 8086?

Tags: microprocessor, cpu, 8085

I know that the minimum distance between any 2 segments is be 16 locations (10H) , but some say its 16 bytes , how is that possible if the the locations are of 2 bytes each. It would total to 32 bytes of minimum size for a segment.

Comment: You already have a question on this topic, do not post another.  If this is really still confusing to you, and still relevant, consult any of the ample instructional materials that were created when this platform had its heyday.  Besides, your idea that "locations are of 2 bytes each" is fundamentally wrong, as explained at your existing question, this is a byte-addressed platform, as you'll understand when you consider the need for seamless 8088 compatibility and the role of the AD0 vs BHE signals.

Comment: The addresses (used by the programmer) are byte based, 16 locations is 16 bytes.  8086/8088 have byte addressable memories.  If you implement and access the memory as 16 bits wide then sure that is 8 16 bit locations or 16 bytes.  (a byte for that processor is normally defined as 8 bits).    x86 calls 16 bits a word so it would be 8 words or 16 bytes being the minimum distance between segments.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.